# Return the precision of the first non zero digit in a number for measurement error representation function

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, number-representation, rounding

I'd like to return the precision of the first non zero digit in a number. The motivation is so that I can quickly construct my error notation which is the bracketed notation, e.g.
$x = 1.234$ with associated error $\delta x = 0.0015$ I would represent the measurement as $1.23(2)$. I want to automate this so I would:

- Determine the precision of the error -- round up by the next digit. So in pseudo code:

  `DeltaX = 0.0015`
     `DeterminePrecissionValue[DeltaX] (*Would return: 3*)`
     `NumberForm[Numb, {DeltaX, 3}]`
     `NumberForm[Numb, {X, 3}]`
- Based on the above result I would then round the measurement value to
  the precision of the error result and then format accordingly.

Comment: That precision can be obtained using the base 10 log, e.g. `In[72]:= Ceiling[-Log[10, .0015]]

Out[72]= 3`

Comment: Elementary mathematics comes to the rescue again. Thanks @DanielLichtblau!